# Python Beginner, get the index of the list if the int inside subset appeared in the original list

Tags: python, for-loop

```
grads = [12,34,56,78,34]

subset = [12,56]


for elem in subset:
   grads_index = np.where(elem == grads)
   display = grads[grads_index[0]]
```

The aim of this code is trying to get the index of grads array using the numbers from the subset. so, for example, the 56 happened to be in both array, I hope to get an index of 56 in grads array which is 2. so that I can retrieve the 56 from grads array using the index.

I tried to print out the grads_index and returns an empty array

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I got this error with the code:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Expected output:

```
 12
 56
```

Comment: Please send text, not images of text.

Comment: Would you write more clearly what is your input and your expected output? Why are you using NumPy?

Comment: As a tip: you can simplify your for loop by doing: `for elem in subset:`. This way `elem` will be what `NumInfos` is in your code.

Comment: The expected output is identical to one of the inputs. You need no code to solve this.

Comment: Are you after something like [this](https://pastebin.com/TnR1vquT)?

Comment: What you describe in word seems to be simply `[grads.index(x) for x in subset if x in grads]`. How that is related to your expected output I do not really understand.

Comment: Either use Numpy or don't. Calling Numpy functions on built-in lists is just not going to be what you want. I recommend spending a few months making sure you know how to do things without Numpy, and then you can study the specific ways to use Numpy for the things it's good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grads = [12,34,56,78,34]
```

This is a native Python list, not a Numpy array.

Because of that,

```
elem == grads
```

cannot use Numpy's operator overloads to create a mask. Before `np.where` is called, Python evaluates `elem == [12,34,56,78,34]`, finds that it is `False` (of course an integer is not equal to a list), and then `np.where(False)` is an empty array.

If you have a Numpy array to begin with:

```
grads = np.array([12, 34, 56, 78, 34])
```

then it will work, but you can do it even more simply:

```
grads[elem == grads]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here, and because you are a beginner I will try to details. (you may want to take a look to pep8 which is a convention on how (where to put space capital letter etc...) to write code)

First if you don't need NumPy you may want to take a look to list.index(x) methods which return the first index which corresponding value is x.

```
grads = [12, 34, 56, 78, 34]
subset = [12, 56]

results = []
for elem in subset:
    results.append(grads.index(elem))
print(results)
```

Using numpy where you miss an important part, it should be apply to NumPy array:

```
grads = np.array([12, 34, 56, 78, 34]) 
np.where(grads==56) 
(array([2]),)
# Or may be more convenient:
x = np.where(grads==56) 
print(x)
[2]
```

Note that NumPy where is a very nice tool that can allow returning value that match some criteria or modify them

example returns all pair number and multiply impair number by two:

```
grads = np.array([12, 34, 56, 78, 34, 35])
np.where((grads % 2) == 0, grads, grads *2) 
array([12, 34, 56, 78, 34, 70])
```